# How to create number six using three zeroes?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

How to create number 6 using only three 0, any arithmetic operation is allowed?
I know it is possible, but I don't know how...

Comment: $(0! + 0! + 0!)!$

Comment: Thanks, I think that is it!

Comment: Chop two of the zeros into two semicircles, put them back together as 3s.  Then 3+3+0=6

Comment: With only 2 zeroes , one can write 8. No operator or function is needed

Answer (score 5):

$6=\left(\cos(0)+\cos(0)+\cos(0)\right)!$

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I don't think functions should be used. It could be lot easier if they could.

Comment: I would argue that $\cos{0}$ is not an arithmetic operation (-1)

Answer (score 4):

Daniel Fischer's answer of $(0! + 0! + 0!)!$ is probably the best answer, however if we're allowed to use *any* function that is commonly expressed as a symbol (e.g. `sqrt`, `abs`, `ceil`) then we can express $6$ using only a single $0$ [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ceil%28abs%28sqrt%28-0!%29!!%29%29!) : $\lceil |\sqrt{-0!}!!|\rceil ! = \lceil | i!!|\rceil ! = \lceil \approx 2.7\rceil ! = 3! = 6$